# 'e' is a bad directive in format '%e %B %Y'

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, python-datetime

I'm trying to convert a string given in the "DD MM YYYY" format into a datetime object. I expect the day integer in my output to consist of a single digit if the day in the date is in single digits. For example, the input '1 May 2014' should be converted to '1 May 2014' after converting into a datetime object instead of '01 May 2014'.

For this purpose, I have used the %e format for converting the day in my output date. Here's the code for the same:

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

s = "1 July 2013"
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%e %B %Y")  

print d.strftime("%e %B %Y")
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: 'e' is a bad directive in format '%e %B %Y'
```

What's wrong with the formatting ? I'm using Python 2.7, if that helps.

Comment: where exactly did you find `%e`?

Comment: @behzad.nouri http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm

Comment: why don't you use python documentation itself? refer to [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Check out [strftime.org](http://strftime.org/) - `%e` is not a valid formatting string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`%e` is not a format code guaranteed to be processable by Python's `datetime.strftime`. Consult the [table here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for the list of format codes Python is guaranteed to support. However, since CPython's `strftime` calls the underlying C library's strftime, on some OS's, such as Linux, the [`%e` format code exists](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html).

---

The [CPython source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0533f148fb49/Modules/timemodule.c#l554) says,

> Other codes may be available on your platform.  See documentation
>   for\n\ the C library strftime function.\n"

---

There is no other format code (guaranteed to exist) which behaves like `%e`. So if your system does not have `%e` or you want your code to be cross-platform compatible, use string formatting, as shown by [Zacrath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24586993/190597) or [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24587002/190597).

Answer (score 5):

You can intermix string formatting and attribute access with the `strftime` style using `str.format`, eg:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = "1 July 2013"
d = datetime.strptime(s, "%d %B %Y")
 # 2013-07-01 00:00:00
out = '{0.day} {0:%B %Y}'.format(d)
# 1 July 2013
```

Comment: Note that `%e` adds a space if the day contains only on digit.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be a directive for what you want. You can either make do with the zero padding or you can change the last line to `print d.strftime("%d %B %Y").lstrip('0')`.